# Neural Networks

Tags: neural-network

I want to learn more about AI and neural networks.  I have some basic idea what it is and how it works, but I want to find a good book or tutorial with good explanations.

Anyone know of some good material ( that is not too technically written ) to read on the subject?

C# implementations are also helpful.

Comment: I have no idea why this question was 'closed as not constructive'!! I found both the question and answer to be good!

Comment: I just don't understand why some people are so fussy, if they don't understand a question it is just their fault.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Good question... There is a impressive collection of books and online texts on the subject of neural networks (NN), but many of them are either very technical or focus on somewhat specific domains of application of the NN, artificial vision, pattern recognition and signal processing being the "natural" leaders in this genre.

I'd like to second Chaos' recommendation of
   ***Fundamentals Of Neural Networks***
   Architectures, Algorithms And Applications
   by Laurene Fausett

For an introduction to the field, this book strikes a good balance in terms of accessibility, detail and coverage.  The alternative are older books circa 1995-2000 which tend to be a be more of the vulgarization type.

You can also wet your appetite with online resources such as:

- A tutorial from [learnartificialneuralnetworks.com](http://www.learnartificialneuralnetworks.com/)  (the site itself also has several good references)
- A [class at Williamette University](http://www.willamette.edu/~gorr/classes/cs449/intro.html)
- When all fails, a quick scan of [NN FAQs](ftp://ftp.sas.com/pub/neural/FAQ.html)

Finally, at the risk of confusing you, at a time when you need a broad view on the subject, I'd like to plug a specific type of neural network: [Numenta's Hierarchical Temporal Memory](http://www.numenta.com/Numenta_HTM_Concepts.pdf) concept.

Comment: Upvote for the NN FAQ. This is always a good reference. For beginners this part is especially useful: ftp://ftp.sas.com/pub/neural/FAQ2.html#A_help (Help! My NN won't learn! What should I do?).

Comment: Excellent answer. Just what I was looking for.

Comment: NN FAQ ! no more words to say. thanks mjv . @alfa thanks for the attention

Answer (score 7):

Checkout http://ml-class.org an online distant education by Stanford, Prof. Andrew Ng is taking the classes, i think it is the best way to get into Neural Networks and machine learning. Also a similar class on Artificial Intelligence: http://ai-class.com taken by Prof. Peter Norvig, Sebastian Thrun. I cannot say if the videos and course materials will be online even when the course ends, but if it stays then it would be a very good resource.

Also have a look at this book: [Neural Networks - A Systematic Introduction by Raul Rojas](http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/rojas/neural/index.html.html). This will give details about ANN.

**EDIT**

Also checkout the upcoming Coursera Neural Network class: https://www.coursera.org/course/neuralnets

Answer (score 6):

I found [Fausett's *Fundamentals of Neural Networks*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0133341860) very accessible.

Answer (score 5):

I have been working with Neural Networks for about 10 years, and still have [Neural Networks: A Comprehensive Foundation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132733501) on my desk.

Answer (score 2):

There are some good articles on code project, here is just a few:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/NeuralNetwork_1.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Backprop_ANN.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/GA_ANN_XOR.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/encogintroxorcs.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You may like to try using [FANN](http://leenissen.dk/fann/wp/), it has bindings for C# (I use the C library) and comes with examples to help get you started.

Answer (score 2):

Try Simon Haykin's book at:

[http://www.amazon.com/Neural-Networks-Learning-Machines-Edition/dp/0131471392/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1331331157&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131471392)

However, the best way do it the http://ml-class.org. It is a step-by-step tutorial on solving a few interesting ML problems.